# Failing to connect with SQL server using windows authentication with java program using jdbc driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sqlexception

I am trying to access the QA database hosted on my company's local server using the java program having jdbc driver. (This database I am authorized and can manually access through SQL MAnagement Studio)

Its failing for me with the exception as below:
**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:88ef2ba1-3a53-4f07-a76f-3f0fbb756341".**

I am not much experienced in establishing connections with sql jdbc. Kindly help me in getting this issue resolved so that I can execute the SQL queries. Please find below the artifacts:

```
package tokenCode;

import java.sql.*;

public class SQLQueries {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
            
            Connection connectionUrl = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://lenwsxxxx\\casqa:1433;database=SBSxxxxx;integratedSecurity=true");  

            
            Statement stmt=connectionUrl.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
            while(rs.next())  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
            connectionUrl.close();  
            }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
            }  
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled in SQL server configuration manager

Comment: You can access via SSMS with the same connection string on the same PC?

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes through SSMS, I can access this server using windows authentication in the same PC. Could there be something wrong or missing in the Connection string I am trying to hit in program?

Comment: _using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption_ should be a clue. Either Java isn't trusting the certificate presented by SQL Server (likely, because it's probably self-signed, try adding `;trustServerCertificate=true` to your connection string), or Java and SQL Server can't agree on a mutual set of TLS protocol versions and cipher suites.

Comment: Also, try to include stack traces - as text - in your questions. Nobody want to retype sections of stack traces from screen shots while trying to help you with your question.